# Sonarlint CLI: How to analyze multiple java files with sonarlint CLI

Tags: sonarlint

I have a large java code. I want to analyze selected java files with `sonarline cli`. For single file, it is working fine.

Single file:
`sonarlint --src "src/com/abc/**/myjava1.java"`

Now suppose I have two java files and want to analyze with sonarlint cli

Multiple file:
`sonarlint --src "src/com/abc/**/myjava1.java, src/com/xyz/**/myjava2.java"`

But this does not analyze any file.

Please suggest how to analyze two or more files / directories using `sonarlint CLI`

Answer (score 0):

You can use "{,}" syntax for multiple files. For instance, try:

`sonarlint --src "{src/com/abc/**/myjava1.java,src/com/xyz/**/myjava2.java}"`